# How to create do_populate_sysroot_append task in yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded

How could we add some additional kernel files to sysroot directory? I want to extend `do_populate_sysroot` task, how can we  to copy few more files into sysroot after `do_populate_sysroot` and before `do_package`? I tried to create `do_populate_sysroot_append()` in recipe  but it is getting parsing error. How could we add file in sysroot after `populate_sysroot` and before `do_package` task starts? How can we create new task in between?

Answer (score 6):

`do_populate_sysroot` is a python function so if you append it with shell then parse errors are to be expected.

If you want to stage more files then you can either append `sysroot_stage_all` or write a function that calls `sysroot_stage_dir` and add it to `SYSROOT_PREPROCESS_FUNCS`.

There are examples of both of these methods in oe-core.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of @ross-burton I searched for recipes that append to `sysroot_stage_all` and found for instance `poky/meta/recipes-core/meta/signing-keys.bb`.

Anyway this is useful if you have a package which packages files in a non-standard directory in the sys root directory and a depending package needs to access these files.

Adding something of the style below accomplishes the task for me.

```
sysroot_stage_all_append () {                                     
    sysroot_stage_dir ${D}${sysconfdir}/pki ${SYSROOT_DESTDIR}${sysconfdir}/pki
}
```

Answer (score 2):

modify the "SYSROOT_DIRS" variable in your kernel recipe would be a easy soultion,

```
SYSROOT_DIRS += "${localstatedir}"
```

with the above change, the "var" directory will also be copied to sysroot.

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SYSROOT_DIRS